# Doesn't Sanskrit use adpositions of any kind?

Tags: grammar, cases, sanskrit, adpositions

For some reason, the Wikipedia article makes no mention of any adpositions of any kind. I find it highly unbelievable that the language makes no use of such. It has a case system, but there's only 8 cases. Even Finnish with its massive 15 cases still makes use of some postpositions (if you can call them that).

Of course, I know Wikipedia isn't the most reliable source of information, but you know, its hard to find free reference grammars online. I don't get why the article would omit something like that. Really, all the article gives is the language's seemingly innumerable declensions and conjugations.

Answer (score 3):

Sanskrit has prepositions, in the [Wiktionary is a category for them](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Sanskrit_prepositions).

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to jknappen's answer, here is a relevant page on prepositions from MacDonnell's Sanskrit grammar available freely online on Wikisource: [link](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3ASanskrit_Grammar_by_Whitney_p1.djvu/442). There are many other reference grammars for Sanskrit that you can find by Googling "Sanskrit grammar pdf" or the like.

As for your actual question, Sanskrit has a few postpositions that are commonly used:

- *prati* : towards [+acc]
- *saha* : with [+ins]
- *vinā* : without [+ins, acc, or abl]

A lot of the words in the Wiktionary category are actually preverbs or prefixes. Sanskrit doesn't really have true prepositions.